# Why is the size 48 instead of 44?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
class B{ int arr[10];  
};  
class D1: virtual public B{  
};  
class D2: virtual public B{
};  
class Derived: public D1,public D2{};  
int main()  {  
  cout  <<  sizeof(D1)  <<  endl; 
  cout  << sizeof(Derived)  <<  endl;   
}
```

The output is 48 and 56.
Sizeof(Derived) = Sizeof(Arr) + Sizeof(D1 vptr) + Sizeof(D2 vptr) = 40 + 4 + 4 = 48. Isn't it correct?

Comment: 48 and 44 should be the output x86 Machine

Comment: In a typical implementation of virtual functions, compiler places a VPTR with every object. Compiler secretly adds some code in every constructor to this.

Comment: Please change to 48 and 44 or it is confusing sizeof(Derived) should bigger than sizeof(D1)

Comment: And how can you get 56 and 48? I try different -march=i686 x86-64 can't get this 56 and 48.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does virtual keyword increase the size of derived a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903596/why-does-virtual-keyword-increase-the-size-of-derived-a-class)

Comment: Could you please elaborate, why you think it should be 44?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc OP seems to be aware of vtable pointers, otherwise he/she would not expect the Derived to be bigger in size. Maybe not aware/forgot that this pointer is 8byte large?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. My mistake, SIzeof(Derived) = 48 I expected. But it is 56. Is it because _vptr is of size 8 Bytes?

Comment: @ead I already saw that an retracted the vote right away

Comment: No they shouldn't. Why do you expect them to?

Comment: When I ran this program on my 64 box the result is 48 and 56 for D1 and Derived respectively. Also the same is having output as 44 and 48 on 32 bit OS box

Comment: Please [edit] and update the question with relevant data. Make sure you explain *why* you expect 44 and 48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware, that a `Derived`-object has two vtable-pointers, I'm not going to explain the data layout to you.

The reason for the mismatch is quite simple: A pointer needs 4 byte on a 32bit system and 8 byte on a 64bit-system (after all the address space is now bigger than can be handled by a 32bit value).

Thus we have:

- 32bit: `sizeof(Arr) + sizeof(D1 vptr) + sizeof(D2 vptr)=40+4+4=48`
- 64bit: `sizeof(Arr) + sizeof(D1 vptr) + sizeof(D2 vptr)=40+8+8=56`

Similar for `D1`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the same. The size of vptr on basis of OS architecture is causing the difference. But I'm not sure on that point. Now it's clear

Answer (score -1):

Runtime size of a class is implementation (i.e compiler) dependent. Look at this [tutorial](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html). Implementation decide the size depending upon many factors e.g. number of bits in processor bits, order of objects, virtual functions, base class etc.

The standard talks about class's [object representation and its value representation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).

**OBJECT REPRESENTATION**

`sizeof(T)` gives you size of object representation.

**VALUE REPRESENTATION**

There are only few bits in whole `sizeof(T)` storage that actually contains the value represented by the object.

Comment: It doesn't depend on static functions. Most of the bits in `sizeof T` contain the object's values.